# Installing Foundation templates, node modules not installed

Tags: node.js, npm, zurb-foundation, html-email

I'm attempting to get the Zurb stack up and running to work on a project using their templates. The directions can be found here https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/sass-guide.html.

When I attempt to run `foundation new --framework emails` I get problems during the install namely that `Node modules not installed` and to try and run `npm install` manually.

I've verified that node is installed by doing a `node -v`. I'm running 10.16.0.

I have also ran `npm install` manually inside my project folder. I get various errors. some include `failed at the nod-sass@3.13.1 postinstall script. This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.`

Comment: Please open an issue at https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues as this can be any proble (missing global dependencies like Python 2 to build node-sass) You have not provided enough information.

Comment: Sure thing. What other information will I need to provide?

Comment: The full output in your terminal after running the `npm install` command.